On Android (Google Pixel 8), how to bridge networks between a USB-tethered device and a device connected to the device's Wifi hotspot?
I want to establish a low-latency, high-throughput connection between a PC and a Meta Quest 3 for a high-quality Steam Link using existing devices instead of buying a dedicated router. My Android Google Pixel 8 supports a Wi-Fi 6E hotspot, and I’m using USB tethering to connect the PC to the phone; however, the devices can't communicate because they’re on different subnets:

VR headset (Wi-Fi hotspot): 192.168.76.x/24
PC (USB tethering): 192.168.210.x/24

How can I configure my Pixel 8 to bridge these networks and allow the devices to talk to each other?

Isn't USB tethering the other way around? Using your simcard as internet access point for your PC, and not the other way around?

You really don't want Android acting as a router or a switch, it's not a secure OS for that, nor designed for that; however, to do so would likely require rooting it since managing network traffic requires root permissions.

Please read the tags before posting your question. You are asking an off-topic question. See [help/on-topic].
